# Erro ao testar a funcionalidade de inserção na classe de teste

Tags: java

Eu criei um projeto usando framework quarkus de uma api-rest. Iniciei a criação das classes de testes para a projeto. A base de dados para os testes é o banco de dados H2. A primeira classe a ser testada é a classe de controller da entidade de "user"(UserResourceTest.java); no método para testar a funcionalidade de inserção de um registro de "user" estou tomando um erro HttpStatus 500. Segue informações do log com o erro:

```
2023-05-07 20:49:12,808 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, hibernate-orm-panache, hibernate-validator, jdbc-h2, jdbc-postgresql, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jsonb, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        users
        (id, age, name) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?)
2023-05-07 20:50:32,376 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-0) SQL Error: 42104, SQLState: 42S04
2023-05-07 20:50:32,377 ERROR [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-0) Table "USERS" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into users (id, age, name) values (default, ?, ?) [42104-214]
2023-05-07 20:50:32,407 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) HTTP Request to /users failed, error id: 423df137-a754-4500-be57-0012d85d487c-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

Segue abaixo a configuração do application.properties e das classes para serem analisadas.

application.properties

```
#GLOBAL
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=root123

quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quarkus-social-db
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16

#TEST
%test.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
%test.quarkus.datasource.username=sa
%test.quarkus.datasource.password=

%test.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:quarkus-social-test-db
%test.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generated=drop-and-base
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
```

Classe User.java

```
package io.github.dougllasfps.model;

import lombok.Data;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

}
```

Classe UserResource.java

```
package io.github.dougllasfps.controllers;

import io.github.dougllasfps.dtos.CreateUserRequest;
import io.github.dougllasfps.dtos.ResponseError;
import io.github.dougllasfps.model.User;
import io.github.dougllasfps.repository.UserRepository;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheQuery;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.Set;

@Path("/users")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private Validator validator;

    @Inject
    public UserResource(UserRepository userRepository, Validator validator) {

        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @POST
    @Transactional
    public Response createUser(CreateUserRequest userRequest) {

        Set<ConstraintViolation<CreateUserRequest>> violentions = validator.validate(userRequest);

        if(!violentions.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseError.createFromValidation(violentions)
                                .withStatusCode(ResponseError.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY_STATUS);
        }

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(userRequest.getName());
        user.setAge(userRequest.getAge());

        userRepository.persist(user);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode()).entity(user).build();
    }
}
```

Classe CreateUserRequest.java

```
package io.github.dougllasfps.dtos;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Data
public class CreateUserRequest {
    @NotBlank(message = "Name is required!")
    private String name;
    @NotNull(message = "Age is required!")
    private Integer age;
}
```

Classe UserResourceTest

```
package io.github.dougllasfps.controllers;

import groovy.json.JsonBuilder;
import io.github.dougllasfps.dtos.CreateUserRequest;
import io.github.dougllasfps.model.User;
import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResource;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@QuarkusTest
class UserResourceTest {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should create user successfully")
    public void createUserTest() {
        var userRequest = new CreateUserRequest();
        userRequest.setName("Fulano");
        userRequest.setAge(20);

        var response =
            given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(userRequest)
            .when()
                .post("/users")
            .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        assertEquals(201, response.statusCode());
        assertNotNull(response.jsonPath().getString("id"));
    }
}
```

Segue abaixo a stack trace do erro:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :201
Actual   :500
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:145)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:528)
    at io.github.dougllasfps.controllers.UserResourceTest.createUserTest(UserResourceTest.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:1002)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:816)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Suppressed: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:105)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:359)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:82)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:147)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:762)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.persist(TransactionScopedSession.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionLazyDelegator.persist(SessionLazyDelegator.java:241)
        at org.hibernate.Session_5b93bee577ae2f8d76647de04cfab36afbf52958_Synthetic_ClientProxy.persist(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.persist(AbstractJpaOperations.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.persist(AbstractJpaOperations.java:96)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheRepositoryBase.persist(PanacheRepositoryBase.java:54)
        at io.github.dougllasfps.repository.UserRepository_ClientProxy.persist(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.dougllasfps.controllers.UserResource.createUser(UserResource.java:48)
        at io.github.dougllasfps.controllers.UserResource_Subclass.createUser$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.dougllasfps.controllers.UserResource_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:133)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:104)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:38)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:58)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:33)
        at io.github.dougllasfps.controllers.UserResource_Subclass.createUser(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3914)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:329)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756)
        ... 52 more
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "USERS" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into users (id, age, name) values (default, ?, ?) [42104-214]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8385)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8369)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8358)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8328)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1632)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:814)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:1044)
        at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.ConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper.java:694)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
        ... 71 more

2023-05-07 20:52:46,894 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) quarkus-social stopped in 0.061s
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58403', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Qual seria a razão para a ocorrência desse erro?

Essa questão foi respondida no stackoverflow gringo. Quem quiser conferir veja o link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204551/error-testing-insert-functionality-in-test-class

Answer (score -2):

O erro ocorre porque o H2 está sendo utilizado para a execução dos testes e, portanto, ele não possui a tabela "users" criada. A mensagem de erro específica, "Table "USERS" not found (this database is empty)", indica que a tabela não existe no banco de dados em uso.

Para resolver isso, você deve garantir que o H2 esteja sendo corretamente configurado no arquivo application.properties. Verifique se as propriedades de configuração do H2 estão prefixadas com %test, que é o prefixo padrão do Quarkus para propriedades de configuração de testes. A propriedade quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url deve estar apontando para o banco de dados em memória H2, que é criado automaticamente pelo Quarkus durante a execução dos testes.

Verifique se a configuração do H2 em seu application.properties está semelhante à configuração abaixo:

```
#TEST
%test.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
%test.quarkus.datasource.username=sa
%test.quarkus.datasource.password=

%test.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:quarkus-social-test-db
%test.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generated=drop-and-create
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
```

Observe que, além da propriedade quarkus.datasource.db-kind ter sido configurada com o valor "h2", as propriedades foram configuradas com o prefixo %test. Também foi adicionado o valor drop-and-create à propriedade quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generated, para que o banco de dados seja recriado a cada vez que os testes são executados.

Certifique-se de que a tabela "users" é criada pelo Hibernate durante a inicialização do aplicativo. Para isso, você pode usar a anotação @Entity na classe User e definir a tabela em que ela será mapeada com a anotação @Table(name = "users").

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eu tenho a impressão que a comunidade quer acabar com SOpt. Não vejo outra explicação. A resposta do @Waldir está correta (ainda que possa ser melhorada). Parece existir uma "força oculta" que negativa as respostas de pessoas com pouca reputação, independentemente do conteúdo da resposta. Isso acaba com a disposição de qualquer um em responder aqui. Enquanto os figurões de outrora estão preocupados em migrar suas contas para outras plataformas, novos contribuintes são desencorajados a responder perguntas com esse tipo de comportamento dos moderadores.